# How to stop elements misbehaving when browser is resized?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web designing and stack overflow , i'm learning from "The Odin Project" . In the course i have to build a look a like of "www.google.com" without any functionality. I completed it using  Html and css . now when i resize the browser window the elements in my html are moving and resizing .

I searched for a solution in the stack overflow some of guys answered to use a wrap element to wrap all the content in the body and to keep min-width attribute to it.

I tried to use wrap div but the problem is still present .

```css
img{
  margin:auto; border:1px solid black; position:absolute;
  top:30%; left:38%; width:295px; min-width:295px;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
li{
  padding:4px; display:inline;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
nav{
  position:absolute; right:2%; top:0%;
}
#search{
  position:absolute; left:30%; top:50%; width:530px;
  min-width:530px; margin:auto; height:6%;
}
#butt{
  position:absolute; left:37%; top:58%;
  width:325px; min-width:325px; border:1px solid red;
}
#wrap{
  border:1px solid black; width:auto; min-width:1500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet"  >
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrap" >
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="">Gmail</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><button style="color:white; background-color:blue;width:auto;height:28px;">Sign in</button></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
       <img src="http://freeworld.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/google_india_logo1.jpg"/>

       <input type="text" id="search" />

       <div id="butt">
           <ul>
               <li><a href=""><button style="width:auto;height:28px;">Google Search</button></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><button style="width:auto;height:28px;">I'm Feeling Lucky</button></a></li>
           </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The borders present in the elements are intentional.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'misbehave' ? Is it about the elements overlapping each other when changing the height of the window?

Comment: yes elements overlapping into each other and width and height of the elements are also changing ...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you positioned the elements absolute, not the wrap.
As currently posted the wrap doesn't do anything.

Try to position the wrap absolute and the elements inside the wrap relative

```
#wrap {
   position: absolute;
   top: 30%; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center; // important
}
```

You will then need to re position your content inside this element

```
img {
   // position: absolute <-- remove this & all top left right bottom
   margin: 0 auto;
   ... // rest of your css
}

#search {
   // position: absolute <-- remove this & all top left right bottom
   margin: 10px auto;
   ... // rest of your css
}

#butt{
   // position: absolute <-- remove this & all top left right bottom
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-align : center;
   // Remove width attribute
   ... // rest of your css
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a rough example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLeNXE?editors=110 (really rough - navigation should be placed outside the wrap to append to to the top again)

Comment: Thanks for the response .   Any hint on how to resolve the same problem when we have a sticky navigation bar(navigation bar fixed on top(position:fixed)).

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Without the fiddle all I can say is that you have the same strucutre. Outer wrap is fixed, inner content isn't.

Comment: http://codepen.io/asmteja/pen/dGVGOv                   when browser width is decreased links and search box are jumping into next line.

Comment: To get rid of this you can set a min-width for the header element (you should also do this for your body then) your code is a little bit messy therefore i have problems to show to you correctly using your code: please refer to following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzazc1ev/

Comment: Got it .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the absolute css when you can rather use margins and padding to style appropriately. Your absolute CSS along with the percentage positions are making the elements flexible. Avoid this because also in the future it is bad for responsive designs

Comment: Not sure about this - I don't think you can say that absolute positioning is bad for responsive designs. This really depends on the use-case. Also this question wasn't refering to any 'best-practices' to create the result, but about why the elements are overalapping on resize. In addition your answer doesn't provide a real solution to the question, just a hint. This should actually be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: @sphinx .  Thanks , any hint on how to resolve same problem on a div with position fixed .